# What is the quickest way to determine why an integration test failed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, minitest, activesupport

I have the following:

```
  test "should update deal" do
    patch user_deal_url(@user, @deal), params: { deal: { name: @deal.name+'xxx' } }
    # p @response.body
    # p @deal.errors.full_messages
    assert_select ".alert", false   # should not have alert
    assert_redirected_to dashboard_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select ".alert", "Deal was successfully updated."
  end
```

It only says:

```
Failure:
DealsControllerTest#test_should_update_deal [C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/test/controllers/deals_controller_test.rb:73]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
```

I thought I could print `@deal.errors.full_messages` but it's not the same `@deal` in the controller. I'm able to print the entire response body and copy it into Notepad++ and search for the error messages, but it's so tedious. I thought I can assert that `.alert` doesn't exist and it would tell me what it actually was. I added

```
assert_select "#error_explanation", false   # should not have error
```

But that only told me that it exists, not why it failed.

```
Expected exactly 0 elements matching "#error_explanation", found 1..
Expected: 0
  Actual: 1
```

So how do you quickly determine why a model is failing to save or update in a controller during testing?

Rails 5.0.2

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

---

My solution causes subsequent `assert_select` statements to fail! Just having `puts css_select('#error_explanation')` makes the last `assert_select` fail, but commenting it out makes it succeed. Why?

I entered a Rails bug for that in the mean time: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29367

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put

```
    puts css_select('#error_explanation')
```

right after the `put`/`patch` and it prints

```
# Running:

<div id="error_explanation">
<h2>
2 errors
prohibited this deal from being saved:
</h2>
<ul>
<li>Size can't be blank</li>
<li>Size is not a number</li>
</ul>
</div>
F

Failure:
```

I'm still looking for something better as leaving this line in causes subsequent `assert_select`s to fail!